# initialize method for an index action presenter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, initialization, presenter

I want to make a presenter for an index action for `Event`.

here is what it looks like. there will be more methods and things added to the presenter and the view, but right now I just want to get this working:

```
class EventPresenter

  def initialize(events, template)
    @events = events
    @template = template
  end

  def h
    @template
  end

  def event_title
    h.link_to event.name, event_path(event)
  end
end
```

index.html.erb:

```
<% present @events do |event_presenter| %> <tr>
    <td><%= event_presenter.event_title %></td>
<% end %>
```

application helper:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def present(object, klass = nil)
    klass ||= "#{object.class}Presenter".constantize
    presenter = klass.new(object, self)
    yield presenter if block_given?
    presenter
  end
end
```

events_controller:

```
  def index
    @events = Event.all.map{ |event| EventPresenter.new(event) }
   # render json: @events
  end
```

the way it is now, I'm getting the `wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)` error for the presenter's initialize method. I was trying to see which of the two objects is not getting passed into the initializer by removing either `@events` or `@template`, such as:

```
  def initialize(template)
    @template = template
  end
```

but, in both cases the app breaks at the `klass ||=` line of the application_helper with `uninitialized constant ArrayPresenter`, while it's supposed to be looking for the `EventPresenter` constant.

Full trace:

```
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `const_get'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `block in constantize'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:257:in `each'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:257:in `inject'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:257:in `constantize'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:66:in `constantize'
app/helpers/application_helper.rb:3:in `present'
app/views/events/index.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_events_index_html_erb__1682590753278671208_70298040094320'
actionview (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_view/template.rb:158:in `block in render'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
actionview (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_view/template.rb:348:in `instrument'
actionview (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_view/template.rb:156:in `render'
actionview (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionview (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:42:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionview (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:41:in `instrument'
actionview (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `block in render_template'
actionview (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
actionview (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
actionview (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionview (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionview (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:103:in `_render_template'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
actionview (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:52:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:144:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:36:in `render'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/benchmark.rb:303:in `realtime'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `block in render'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:86:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:42:in `render'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:19:in `default_render'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `block in send_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `tap'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:183:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:27:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:248:in `process_action'
activerecord (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:128:in `process'
actionview (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:262:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:39:in `block in serve'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `each'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `serve'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:724:in `call'
actionview (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_view/digestor.rb:12:in `call'
rack (2.0.0.alpha) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.0.alpha) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.0.alpha) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
rack (2.0.0.alpha) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `context'
rack (2.0.0.alpha) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:214:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
activerecord (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:963:in `call'
activerecord (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_record/migration.rb:558:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:71:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:49:in `call'
web-console (3.1.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:131:in `call_app'
web-console (3.1.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (3.1.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (3.1.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.0.0.beta3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.0.0.beta3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `tagged'
railties (5.0.0.beta3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.0.0.alpha) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.0.alpha) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/load_interlock.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
rack (2.0.0.alpha) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.0.0.beta3) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call'
puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/server.rb:569:in `handle_request'
puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/server.rb:406:in `process_client'
puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/server.rb:271:in `block in run'
puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:114:in `call'
puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:114:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: sure, I just updated the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to wrap `event` objects with a presenter by calling `present` method in a view layer, so doing the same thing in controller looks redundant to me. Moreover, that actually was a line resulting in `wrong number of arguments`, as you wrapped it with a single argument only. Let's remove it:

```
# events_controller
def index
  @events = Event.all
  # we removed redundant EventPresenter.new(event) here
end
```

Next step is your view template. As long as `@events` containts an array of elements (you could check the class of `object` parameter in your `present` helper method), you get `"#{object.class}Presenter".constantize` to end with `"ArrayPresenter".constantize`, and this results in an error as there is no such class as `ArrayPresenter`. What you could do here to solve this is to iterate an array first:

```
<% @events.each do |event| %>
  <% present event do |event_presenter| %>
```

Another option could be to iterate a collection inside of your helper method. You might be intrested in some existing solutions like [Draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper) gem to get an idea of how they solve the objects wrapping issues.

Comment: ok, finally got around to trying this out. this all makes sense, except what should I change in the EventPresenter file? the app breaks down at `h.link_to event.name, event_path(event)` line with `undefined local variable or method `event' for #<EventPresenter:`.

Comment: @sivanes there is no such local variable as `event` in that method, so the error seems legit. you got `@events` array only. more than that, you gonna have issues with calling `h` from presenter class (as that helper is not defined there). and your `template` parameter in initializer is a reserved rails word, so you should probably rename it. note that Presenters are advanced topic and you should be prepared for loads of such issues.

Comment: so, no quick fix here, I take it?

Comment: `uninitialized constant ArrayPresenter` error should be fixed by a solution above. other issues go out of this thread frame.